# jQuery can't get top parent?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a simple html code like this:

```
<section class="main">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <header class="verticalCenter">
            ...
            </header>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Plus, I have this jQuery:

```
function verticalCenter(el) {
    el.each(function() {
        var elHeight = $(this).outerHeight(true),
            parentHeight = $(this).parent('section').outerHeight(true),
            marginTop = (parentHeight - elHeight)/2;

        $(this).css('margin-top',marginTop);
    })
}

verticalCenter($('.verticalCenter'))
```

Problem is - jQuery doesn't see `section.main`. What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want `.closest()`, not `.parent()`

```
  parentHeight = $(this).closest('section').outerHeight(true),
```

The `.parent()` function checks *only* the immediate parent. Passing it a selector effectively means, "get me the parent, but only if the parent matches this selector; otherwise, give me an empty list."

Answer (score 3):

[`.parent()`](http://api.jquery.com/parent/) only travels one level up the DOM tree. In your code, `$(".verticalCenter")` does not have any direct parent node that matches the selector "section".

[`.closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) meanwhile gets the closest ancestor that matches the passed selector.

```
$(this).closest('section.main')
```